# Image Mosaic Layer Extents Changing Randomly

Tags: geoserver, extents

Any ideas what could cause the extents of a layer to change without me adjusting them?

Every so often I have to go back and reclick on the "compute from native bounds" under Lat/Lon Bounding Box:

[image]

The layer is an image mosaic layer in Geoserver. Nightly a script adds a new geotiff for the current day with the same extent as all previous tiffs inside of the image mosaic layer directory (it's a time series). I also add a new row to the postgis granule index table. But I copy the extend from the previous granules so they should all have the same bounding box. Would any of this possibly trigger Geoserver to change the Lat/Lon Bounding Box? Next time it happens I'll attach a screenshot where the numbers are off.

**More Info - 5/10/2016**

I have about 25 Geoserver layers. When I came in this morning, I checked the bounding box on all the layers and indeed the lat/lon bounding box on one of the layers had changed automatically. However it was a different layer than the four layers that this had happened to yesterday. The ones I fixed yesterday still look ok today. Here is a screenshot taken BEFORE I clicked "Compute from native bounds" to fix it.

[image]

and here is the screen shot after i clicked compute from native bounds
[image]

Also, I have this setup pretty much duplicated on a dev and ops server. Of course it only seems to be happening on the ops server :S

Comment: They are pretty much the same, the differences are in the 8th decimal. Is this causing any problems or is it just annoying?

Comment: I wasn't clear - the screenshot in the question is from AFTER I had clicked on 'compute from native bounds'. After some time those numbers will change to be off by quite a bit more than they currently are.